# clear one timeout, start another

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm auto-refreshing the content on a site using ajax/json. Using jkey, I trigger some posting to the document, and during this action I want to cancel the original setTimeout that's running ("reloading" at 2 mins) - and then trigger the entire function "content" again to start over after 5 secs. However, I can't seem to stop "reloading" properly, neither call "content" after the given seconds. Can anybody spot the error?

```
 <script>
$(function content(){
  function reloading(){
      $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                          
      data: "",                      
      dataType: 'json',                    
      success: function(data)          
      {
        var id = data[0];              
          _id = id;
        var vname = data[1];           
        var message = data[2]; 
        var timestamp = data[3]; 
        var field1 = data[4]; 
        _field1 = field1;
        var val2 = parseInt(field1, 10) ;
        _val2 = val2;
        $('#output').hide().html( message ).fadeIn("slow");   
         $('#username').hide().html( vname +":" ).fadeIn("slow");
      setTimeout(reloading,120000);
 }
      });
  }
  reloading();
}); 

  $(document).jkey('a',function() {
     $.post("update.php", { "id": _id} )
      $('#output').hide().html( "<i>thx" ).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#username').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg2').fadeOut("fast");
        clearTimeout(reloading);
       setTimeout(content,5000);
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clearTimeout` should get the unique "key" that is returned by `setTimeout`. So when setting, assign the return value to global variable:

```
window["reload_timer"] = setTimeout(reloading,120000);
```

Then have this:

```
clearTimeout(window["reload_timer"]);
```

Comment: Now, that worked like a charm! The last issue now is calling the function "content" again after 5 seconds. I tried the same method with no result. What am I missing out on here?

Comment: No point calling `content` again - the only thing it's doing is calling  `reloading` function which already calls itself again in the AJAX callback.

Answer (score 3):

You must save the `setTimeout()` id in order to later clear it with `clearTimeout()`. Like this:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){someFunction()}, 5000);//this will set time out
//do stuff here ...
clearTimeout(timeoutID);//this will clear the timeout - you must pass the timeoutID
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides saving the timeout id as mentioned in other posts, your `function reloading` is created inside `function content` and since you create no closure to it, it's unreachable from the rest of the program.

```
$(function content(){
    function reloading(){
        console.log('RELOADING');
    }
    reloading();
}); 

// Can't reach `content` or `reloading` from here
```

You have to do something like this:

```
var reloading, content, reloadingTimeoutId, contentTimeoutId;


reloading = function () {
    console.log('RELOADING');
    $.ajax(
       // CODE
       success : function (data) {
           // CODE
           reloadingTimeoutId = setTimeout(reloading, 120000);
       }
    )
};


content = function () {
    reloading();
};


$(document).jkey('a',function() {
    // CODE
    clearTimeout(contentTimeoutId);
    contentTimeoutId = setTimeout(content,5000);
});
```

It's kinda difficult writing this better not knowing the bigger picture. With this, `content` will be called after 5 seconds and as long as `reloading` succeeds it will callback itself every 120 seconds. Please observe that `reloading` is never cleared this way.

Comment: I want to, but I can't seem to get this to work. One thing though, wouldn't it be possible to just call the entire "content" - just making sure it's accessible for the jkey-function?

Comment: That works, but you will create a new `reloading` function every time and throw it away once you exit the scope. If you want to stop the reloading you should call `clearTimeout(reloadingTimeoutId)`. If `content` won't contain more code than in my example you could just call reloading direct from inside `jkey(...`.